# Swift - Setting a gradient to a UITableView Section background

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

This is what I currently have:

```
let topColor = UIColor(red: 2/255, green: 138/255, blue: 191/255, alpha: 1)
let bottomColor = UIColor(red: 1/255, green: 66/255, blue: 125/255, alpha: 1)

func configureGradient() {
    let sectionRect = tableView.rect(forSection: currentSelectedIndex)
    let backgroundView = UIView(frame: sectionRect)
    backgroundView.layer.zPosition = -1
//        backgroundView.backgroundColor = bottomColor

    let gradientLayer = CAGradientLayer()
    gradientLayer.colors = [topColor, bottomColor]
    gradientLayer.locations = [0.0, 1.0]
    gradientLayer.frame = sectionRect
    backgroundView.layer.insertSublayer(gradientLayer, at: 0)

    tableView.addSubview(backgroundView)
}
```

I am calling this after the network call and `tableView.reloadData()`

`currentSelectedIndex` defaults to `0` and changes to the index of the new section when the header is tapped. It's an accordion tableview, so at max only one section is visible at a time.

For some reason this does not work, I'm not sure what I'm missing in the gradient code. I know it is getting the the frame correctly because if I comment out the gradient code and add the background color by itself, it works perfectly fine.

Also, I have the `zPosition` set to `-1`. Without it `backgroundView` covers up the entire view. With it set to `-1` I can see the rest of the view, but it's still blocking user interaction. When I look at the UI Hierarchy it shows it on top of everything. Is there a better way to programmatically adjust the position to be below everything else? I've tried setting it to `-1000` just to be sure, but no luck.

**Recap**:

1. Why does the background color work fine but not the gradient?
2. Is there a better way to adjust the `zPosition` to stop it from blocking access to the UI?

Answer (score 1):

`CAGradientLayer`'s `.colors` expects an array of `CGColor`s, but you're passing it `UIColor`s instead. To fix it, pass the `CGColor` versions of your `UIColor`s:

```
gradientLayer.colors = [topColor.cgColor, bottomColor.cgColor]
```

For some reason `.colors` is declared as type `[Any]`, so the compiler lets it pass, but you end up with a blank gradient.

Answer (score 0):

You should use `CGColor`s instead of `UIColor`s.

```
gradientLayer.colors = [topColor.cgColor, bottomColor.cgColor]
```

Although the parameter is `[Any]?`, the documentation says:

> An array of `CGColorRef` objects defining the color of each gradient stop. Animatable.

Answer (score 0):

For part 2 of my question here is the answer. Remove `addSubview` as well as `zPosition` and use this:

```
tableView.insertSubview(backgroundView, at: 0)
```